# Connecting to MongoDb (or any other db server) with Pyramid

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid

What is the difference between connecting to the MongoDb server with the following two lines in the `models.py` module and then `import models.py` inside `views.py`:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient()['name']
```

versus adding `db` to `request` as described [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/database/mongodb.html) or [here](https://zaiste.net/posts/building_a_restful_api_with_pyramid_resource_and_traversal/)?

I just started playing round with Pyramid and MongoDb, I used the first approach and it works well. Then I found out that people use the second approach.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong / different with your approach. In your case, you'll need to import your `db` in all files that you need it. In the examples, it will already be available in the `request`.

Comment: @AntoineLeclair My views import `models.py`. Most of the job is done inside that module, and when I need `db` inside a view I will import it from `models.py`. I think it's cleaner and more pythonic my way (explicit better than implicit). But I was wondering if I risk to break something or to miss some features provided by the Pyramid infrastructure.

Comment: I think you're 100% right. I guess people do it the other way because when using SQLAlchemy with transactions, it's easier to manage transactions if you inject a `db` scoped for the transaction directly in your request (instead of relying on threadlocals). They're used to that pattern, so they continue to use it with other DBs/libs.

Comment: @AntoineLeclair Thanks, this looks like an answer more than a comment :)

Comment: Actually @AntoineLeclair, I think that's a bit off. The scoped session factory in SQLAlchemy is what you use when you *do* want to use thread locals. The SA docs show that when using module singletons. If you hook things into the request callback, you get to avoid using scoped sessions and are using explicitly managed sessions. I suppose some people put scopes sessions in request callbacks, but that's doing the job twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* with what you're doing, but it's less future proof in case your app is going to become complex. The pattern your using is what sometimes is called "using a module as a singleton". The first time your module is imported, the code runs, creating a module level object that can be used from any other code that imports from this module. There's nothing wrong with this, it's a normal python pattern and is the reason you don't see much in the way of singleton boilerplate in python land.

However, in a complex app, it can become useful to control exactly when something happens, regardless of who imports what when. When we create the client at config time as per the docs example, you know that it gets created when the config (server startup) block is running as opposed to whenever *any* code imports your module, and you know from then on that it's available through your registry, which is accessible everywhere in a Pyramid app through the request object. This is the normal Pyramid best practise: set up all your one-time shared across requests machinery in the server start up code where you create your configurator, and (probably) attach them to the configurator or its registry.

This is the same reason we hook things into request lifecycle callbacks, it allows us to know where and when some piece of per-request code executes, and to make sure that a clean up helper always fires at the end of the request lifecycle. So for DB access, we create the shared machinery in config startup, and at the beginning of a request we create the per-connection code, cleaning up afterwards at the end of the request. For an SQL db, this would mean starting the transaction, and then committing or rolling back at the end.

So it might not matter at all for your app right *now*, but it's good practise for growing code bases. Most of the Pyramid design decisions were made for complex code situations.